# apt-get update leads to obsolete packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

The university where I study hosts an Ubuntu package mirror server, which I normally use to update my repository.
However, right now, I am not in the university and update packages instead from the server from India or the main server.
When I run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, apt-get asks to **downgrade** a large number of packages (1035 in total).

Output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6556854/

A related thing I noticed is that if I open synaptic, the 'latest' packages are all quite old, e.g

libunity-core-5.0-5: Installed version 5.20.0-0ubuntu2, Latest version 5.10.0-0ubuntu6.

Even the latest generic linux header and image are shown to be quite old (in fact, the one that comes during install) -version: 3.2.0.23.25
What is the reason for this happening and how can I rectify it?

System information:

12.04 LTS, 64 bit machine.
Kernel: 3.2.0-56-generic

Output of `apt-cache policy cups-client` :

```
    abhi@abhinav-HP:~$ apt-cache policy cups-client
    cups-client:
      Installed: 1.5.3-0ubuntu8
      Candidate: 1.5.2-9ubuntu1
      Version table:
     *** 1.5.3-0ubuntu8 0
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
         1.5.2-9ubuntu1 0
           2012 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Here you are: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6556958/

Comment: Done. Thanks for sparing your time in attempting an answer.

Comment: @Braiam, could you think of anything that is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen your `sources.list` file, but I'm almost sure that you don't have the `precise-updates` and `precise-security` repositories activated. You should add the following two lines to your `sources.list`

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main universe restricted multiverse
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main universe restricted multiverse
```

Update your lists with `sudo apt-get update` then upgrade as usual.